# Print result from promise map

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi guys I have 2 methods.

```
checkVenueAvailability(venues) {
        var replaced = venues.replace(/\t/g, "");
        var venues = replaced.split(',');
        var length = venues.length;
        Promise.all(venues.map(venue => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                pool.query("SELECT * FROM peminjaman_venue WHERE nama_venue = ?", venue,
                    function (err, rows, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            return reject(err);
                        }
                        return resolve(rows);
                })
            })
        }))
    }
```

And

```
mengajukan_event(req, res) {
        helper.checkVenueAvailability(req.body.venue_1)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

I want to print the result of checkVenueAvailability in mengajukan_event. How to achieve that. My code above just return error. Thankyou.

Comment: You need to return the `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't *returning* anything. Just return the promise from `Promise.all`:

```
    return Promise.all(venues.map(venue => {
//  ^^^^^^
```

---

Also note that there are DB adapters with a Promise-based API available now. Or, if you can't use one, you can use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

```
const promiseQuery = util.promisify(pool.query);
```

Then

```
checkVenueAvailability(venues) {
    var replaced = venues.replace(/\t/g, "");
    var venues = replaced.split(',');
    return Promise.all(venues.map(venue => promiseQuery("SELECT * FROM peminjaman_venue WHERE nama_venue = ?", venue));
}
```

(I also removed `var length = venues.length;` since `length` wasn't used for anything.)

Comment: Need to delete return in new promise, resolve, reject?

Comment: @jordie_f - The way you have it is fine, though it's not how I would do it. I'd just use `if (err) { reject(err); } else { resolve(rows); }`

Comment: For me, I'm a fan of the return option..  It handles the error logic asap, and prevents an extra level of indentation for the rest the logic, and keeps in sync with how a normal error would appear.  eg. We dont place an extra level of indentaion when we throw a normal error..

Comment: @Keith - In which case, `reject(); return;` would be more appropriate. The return value of the callback isn't used, and `reject` has no useful return value, so `return reject();` is misleading. Separately, when "the rest of the logic" is `resolve();`, I don't see an issue. :-) Thankfully, Node-style callbacks are going the way of the Dodo bird, so...

Comment: It's then `if (err) { reject(err); return; }`.. Too many `{}`, so I'm still a fan of `if (err) return reject(err);`  even if the return is a No Op..  The logic of the resolve, is you often have more code that just resolve, you might have transformation etc,.  So all this code has an extra level of indentation,..  As you can see I'm not a fan of over indentation.. :)..  or too many `{}`,. But like you say, it's less of an issue anyway these days..

Comment: @Keith - I'd much rather have a pair of `{}` (they should always be there anyway) and a `return;` than have misleading code.

Comment: `misleading code`  I think if I had to hire a programmer, and he didn't understand -> `if (err) return reject(err);`  I think I might have to kindly ask him to pack his bags.. :)

Comment: @Keith - It's misleading whether people know to ignore the fact it's saying it's returning something that isn't there and isn't used or not. There's no reason to make the person reading the code work harder than necessary (see the concept of "cognitive load"). Anyway, I'm sure we have other things we should be doing. :-)

Comment: Yeah, let's get back to work.. Still don't agree with you.  I agree with most your thoughts, just not this one.. Short circuiting functions for me, has always led to less errors, this is not just Javascript, C++, Delphi etc too.  For me doing the above, the error handling is done on the first line of code, that's it. move onto the rest of the logic.  And how it makes it harder for others to read, baffles me.. :)

Comment: @Keith - I have no problem with short-circuiting functions. I just prefer to make it not misleading. :-) I've found not being misleading has always led to fewer errors, this is not just JavaScript, but C, C#, Java etc. too.

Comment: Totally agree, try and avoid misleading code.  But just don't agree that this is.. Yes, it's returning a value that's of no use, I can see that.  Anyway, it's really just personal taste.  We could all turn into `Douglas Crockford` and have one rule is set, but then we wouldn't have EsLint, and then I'd be sad..

Comment: @Keith :-) Yeah, I prefer pluggable rules a team can agree on, rather than Handed Down From On High, too.